# suspend - Computer hard shutdown when suspending

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, 18.04

I've seen this question has already posted but I still couldn't find any answers. So basically, when I close my laptops lid and reopen it, instead of showing the lockscreen it boots up from the beginning. Instead of suspending it's basically doing a hard shutdown. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, although this used to happen with 17.10 too.

I've already tried this:

- I've checked the settings on Gnome and it's set to Suspend
- I've tried with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"

Also, I've noticed a few things:

- I don't have a swap partition. I installed Ubuntu using the automatic partition tool.
- /var/log/pm-suspend.log is empty

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I might have the same problem. In my case, resume doesn't work even in Windows, so I guess I have some HW-related troubles. BIOS seems to be setup alright in my case. Have you checked the BIOS settings?